# Write the Context free Grammar

Tags: automata

What will be the context-free grammar of $B= A_1.A_2 $
when $A_1 = \{0^n1^n|n\geq 0\}$
$A_2 = \{1^n0^n|n \geq 0\}$
Also verify using a string.

if  the Grammar for
$A_1$: $S_1 \rightarrow 0S_11 | \varepsilon$

$A_2$: $S_2 \rightarrow 1S_20 | \varepsilon$

I am stuck with the value of $S \rightarrow$ ?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. Please show that you have tried solving this by yourself, and ask precisions on the steps you are blocked.

Comment: Nathaniel I am not asking you to do my homework, I did this using union I am stuck with concatenation, I have created separate grammars for A1 and A2 which are A1:S1 → 0S11 | ε
 and A2: S2 → 1S20 | ε I am stuck with the value of S → ?

Comment: You should edit your post to show what you have done, not write it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your grammars for $A_1$ and $A_2$ seem correct. Since you want to compute the concatenation of $A_1$ and $A_2$, you just need to express this fact with the start symbols of $A_1$ and $A_2$.

$S \rightarrow S_1S_2$ is a way to do it.

You can check by computing the derivation that creates the word $001110$.

Comment: Do i check it like this [S = 0 S1 1 = 0 0S1 11 = 0011].
[S=1 S2 0=10]. S→S1S2 = 0011.10 = 001110

Comment: No, the first steps should be $S \rightarrow S_1S_2 \rightarrow 0S_11S_2 \rightarrow$…